# ReactJS - Issue about Insert a dynamic content in Lightbox Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have this React Component. It is working Successfully.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'    
import Lightbox from 'react-lightbox-component';    

const LightBoxTest = () => (

  <div>

    <Lightbox images={[
      {
        src: '../images/int_01.jpg'       
      },
      {
        src: '../images/int_02.jpg'
      },
      {
        src: '../images/int_03.jpg'        
      }
    ]} />
  </div>
);
```

But I want insert the images in a dynamically way by fetching the data from json.db with Axios. How can I do it?

Here is my json.db:

```
{  
  "interiors": [
    {      
      "photos": [      
        "int_01",
        "int_02",
        "int_03" 
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried to do this way and it didn't work. The Axios is fetching successfully the data but it isn't rendering in the screen.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'  
import Lightbox from 'react-lightbox-component';


const URL_INTERIORS = 'http://localhost:3001/interiors';


class LightBoxTest extends Component {


  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      interiors: [],
      interiorsPhotos: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(URL_INTERIORS)
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          interiors: res.data[0],
          interiorsPhotos: res.data[0].photos,             
      })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>    
        <Lightbox images={[
          this.state.interiorsPhotos.map((photo, index) => {
            {
              src: `../images/${photo}.jpg`      
            }
          })
        ]} />

      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default LightBoxTest
```

There isn't any error message and when I check the react dev tool, there render a single blank image like that:

```
<img key="0" className="lightbox-img-thumbnail"></img>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map returns an array and you are wrapping the returned array within another array which causes this behvaiour

Updating to

```
 <Lightbox images={
      this.state.interiorsPhotos.map((photo, index) => {
        return {
          src: `../images/${photo}.jpg`      
        }
      })
    } />
```

will work

To make it more clean you could write it like

```
render() {
    const images = this.state.interiorsPhotos.map((photo, index) => {
           return  {
              src: `../images/${photo}.jpg`      
            }
          })
    return (
      <div>    
        <Lightbox images={images} />
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: Your solution didn't work. There appears an error message:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'thumbnail' of undefined

Comment: Updated the answer. The map function wasn't returning anythign